# Why does the argument below show when not entered in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to run this code in Eclipse, but whenever I try and run with just the argument `-es`, It's like I entered `-es` AND `-h`. Here is the code:

```
public class Option
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        if ( args[0].equals("-en") )
        {
            System.out.println( "Langauge is set to English") ;
        }
        else if ( args[0].equals("-es") )
        {
            System.out.println( "El idioma es espanol") ;
        }
        else if ( args[0].equals("h") ) ;
        {
            System.out.print( "\tHelp\n\n\t-es\tSpanish\n\t-en\tEnglsish" ) ; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Eliminate the `;` in this line:

```
else if ( args[0].equals("h") ) ;
```

Java treats that semicolon as the body of the `else if`, and the block in braces after it would be executed always.

Removing that semicolon would allow the block in braces following it to be treated as the block for the `else if`, which is what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo: you have a `;`after your third `if` statement.

Remove that and it will work.

That happens all the time :D